# How to perform bit extension in system verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, sign-extension

I want to replicate one bit for specific times using replication opreator {} but I get only the first bit as I want and others are zeros whether the bit is zero or one.

```
module(logic output [7:0] a);
assign a={8{1}};
endmodule
```

I get a equals 00000001
Not 11111111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog an *unbased literal* (eg `1`) is (a) decimal, (b) signed and (c) 32-bits. Because of (c),

```
{8{1}}
```

is the same as

```
{8{32'sb00000000000000000000000000000001}}
```

which is a 256-bit number, which then gets truncated to 8-bits when it gets assigned to `a`. This is why you get `a` equal to `8'b00000001`.

You need

```
{8{1'b1}}
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked fine for that case  but if want to extend specific bit from another input like a={8anotherInput[5]}; it does the that  wrong thing

Comment: a={8{anotherInput[5]}}